# How to divide every cell in a column by a constant in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am processing a data set that has about 50 columns, and the same columns are always off by a factor of ten. So, I just want to hardcode the specific columns (starting with F here) and divide every cell in the column by 10. Right now I am getting a "Type Mismatch" error. The code is below:

```
Sub FixData()
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

finalRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

 Set rng = Range("F1:F" & finalRow)
 
 For Each cell In rng
 cell.Value = cell.Value / 10
 Next cell
 
 
  
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there errors, blanks, or text in the range?  Are the numbers stored as text?

Comment: You have finalrow checking column A but you want column F?

Comment: @ScottCraner The numbers are being stored as general, there are some that are blanks and have errors, but not in column F.

Answer (score 4):

why loop when you can simply paste special and divide.

[image]

errors within the cells are ignored.

in vba, here is the code

```
Range("G10").Copy
Range("B2:E8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlDivide
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Answer (score 1):

test if cell is an error and then test if it is a number prior to dividing:

```
Sub FixData()
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

finalRow = Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("F1:F" & finalRow)
 
For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsError(Cell) Then
        If IsNumeric(cell) and cell <> "" Then
            cell.Value = cDbl(cell.Value) / 10
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd think just the `IsNumeric` check is enough, since errors are not numeric.

Comment: `IsNumeric(emptyCellHere)` is True

Comment: @TimWilliams - and that reminded me that pastespecial/divide will have the same effect, populating an empty cell.